# How to make DDL from cursor.description or a select-statement

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

Using cx_Oracle 5.1.2, python 2.7 and Oracle 11g, my situation is as follows:

i have one cx_oracle cursor connected to DB_one i will call cur_input and another cursor connected to DB_two i will call cur_output.

After executing a selection on cur_input, i would like to be able to generate the DDL of it to create a fitting table on cur_output and then insert data into this table coming from cur_input. The problem lies in the datatypes & definitions when creating the table.

In pseudocode, i would like to:

```
CREATE TABLE cur_output.schema.tablename 
          AS 
      SELECT a,b,1,2,decode(1,1,'2',2,3)
        FROM cur_input.schema.tablename
       WHERE 1=2
```

Can all of this be done without:

- having to create the table on the input-side first, and fetch the DDL from it using `DBMS_METADATA.get_ddl`
- using Oracle's DBLINKS

...?

The entries in cur_input.description seem quite useful for this, but i don't feel comfortable translating cx_Oracle.STRING in the cur_input.description directly into a VARCHAR2 for the output-DDL because cx_Oracle.STRING could translate to Oracle's: VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2 or LONG 
(full translation-table: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html   -- chapter: Datatypes)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was painfully simple. Using the cursor.description way: The translation from cx_Oracle's types to Oracle's datatypes can be done unambiguously. I was using documentation from the stone-age is what's the problem...

```
translator = { 'BINARY'         : 'RAW',\
           'BFILE'          : 'BFILE',\
           'BLOB'           : 'BLOB',\
           'CLOB'           : 'CLOB',\
           'CURSOR'         : 'CURSOR',\
           'DATETIME'       : 'DATE',\
           'FIXED_CHAR'     : 'CHAR',\
           'FIXED_UNICODE'  : 'NCHAR',\
           'INTERVAL'       : 'INTERVAL',\
           'LONG_STRING'    : 'LONG',\
           'LONG_UNICODE'   : 'LONG ',\
           'NCLOB'          : 'NCLOB',\
           'NUMBER'         : "NUMBER",\
           'OBJECT'         : 'OBJECT',\
           'ROWID'          : 'ROWID',\
           'STRING'         : 'VARCHAR2',\
           'TIMESTAMP'      : 'TIMESTAMP',\
           'UNICODE'        : "NVARCHAR2" }

str_coltype     # example:  "<type 'cx_Oracle.NUMBER'>"
cx_coltp = re.findall("\.([^\.]+)'>$", str_coltype)[0]
ora_coltp = translator[ cx_coltp ]
```

As it turned out, there is some top notch documentation available here:

http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/module.html#types